# Creating threaded popups in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, pysimplegui

I have trouble creating either multiple windows or popups using PySimpleGUI.
Each window/popup is supposed to be called from a seperate thread and timeout after 2 seconds.
Using following implementation results in (as expected) this error: main thread is not in main loop.
How do I fix that?

```
def get_info():
    while True:
        info = get_details()
        if info:
            layout[]
            window = sgWindow(...)
            while True:
                
                
                event, values = window.read(timeout=1000*2)
                if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED,): break
                if event in ('__TIMEOUT__',):
                    window.close()
                    break
                if event == "X":
                    window.close()
                    close = True
                    break
                if event == "Y":
                    window.close()
                    close = True
                    break

for i in range(x):

    t = threading.Thread(target=get_info())
    t.start()
```

Comment: https://www.PySimpleGUI.org has a lot of info about using threads with PySimpleGUI.  There are numerous demo programs and it's a well-documented feature.

Comment: The solution was to avoid threading on it as much as possible. For anybody else reading this: Just use a queue to queue the incoming calls from the outside threads.

Comment: Threading is OK, but you can only make a single call from a thread into PySimpleGUI, one that communicates back to the main thread.  All other calls are off-limits. Nice job of researching and summarizing.